# How to get the Google Geocoder API geometry values (latitude and longitude) same as Google maps URL latitude and longitude values

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am using Google Maps Geocoding API to get geometry location (lat, lng values) of the address in store locator address filter.

**Example:**

When I used to search an address (Postal code, Street name, Landmark) of Singapore and 
It gives location lat & lng values in geometry results as follows,

**JavaScript method:**

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': "New Bridge Road"}, function(results, status) {});
```

The above JavaScript method and the [Geocoder Request URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20Bridge%20Road&region=SG) API will return as

```
"location" : {
   "lat" : 1.283266,
   "lng" : 103.8426887
},
```

But when I used to search the same address in Google map (https://www.google.co.in/maps), it shows different lat & lng values in the [address bar](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/New+Bridge+Rd,+Singapore/@1.2832714,103.8405,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x31da197370544157:0xaf3357d548998f55!8m2!3d1.283266!4d103.8426887) as

[image]

So here I wanted to have the same zoom level, center position and lat & lng values as [google map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/New+Bridge+Rd,+Singapore/@1.2834504,103.8406443,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x31da197370544157:0xaf3357d548998f55!8m2!3d1.283266!4d103.8426887) for my store locator also.

Comment: Did you try another address, just for testing purpose?

Comment: @fubbe I tried with multiple addresses

Comment: Why do you think the values in the Google Maps URL are more accurate?  Last I checked, that was the center of the map, not the location that resulted from the query.

Comment: @geocodezip I did not think URL values are accurate. Rather than mentioned that I need to achieve the same behaviour of Google maps (same lat & lng, Zoom level and centre position) by using Geocoder API for my store locator.

Comment: @Soliyappan have you tried giving New Bridge Rd, Singapore in the java script method you have?

Comment: @Coder I tried that also, it gives same result set only

Answer (score 0):

Region biasing to `IN` will get you results as on maps.google.co.in:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?new_forward_geocoder=true&address=New%20Bridge%20Road&region=IN

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But by using geocoder API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20Bridge%20Road&region=SG&new_forward_geocoder=true&key=xxxyyyy) I would require the same lat, lng values as (/@1.2833987,103.8406112,17z/) in consumer google maps URL.
Consumer google maps URL: https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+Bridge+Rd,+Singapore/@1.2833987,103.8406112,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x31da197370544157:0xaf3357d548998f55!8m2!3d1.283266!4d103.8426887

Comment: Google Maps URLs are a different thing altogether, and not at all an API you can rely upon. A google.com/maps/place URL is kinda like a Places Details request, it'll only show a specific place if you've gotten the URL by searching on Google Maps. If you modify one such URL, it often won't get you what you want. A google.com/maps/search URL is like a Places Text Search (or Geocoding) request, but it will redirect you to a /maps/place URL if Google Maps concludes there is one result that's "probably" the only one you want. Just use an API if you want something reliable.